# Passing of variables outside the loop in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a simple code that goes like this

```
<?php

echo $passer;

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    $msg = $i;
}

$passer = $msg;

?>
```

My aim is to display the result above the loop. Is there a way to pass the value of $msg so it will be displayed above the loop? Currently the output is:

> Undefined variable: passer

Comment: You need to use a function, code is (generally) read from top to bottom. Wrap your for loop in a function and you can place it anywhere you want, but you will still need to define / declare the `$passer` variable before you can echo it.

Comment: You cannot output above as php is processed top to bottom its an in-order language.  Besides the bigger question is why? what are you hoping to achieve? I cannot think of a single instance where I'd want to echo out code before I'd generated the variables value.  Now if you mean you want to inject it in to the html above a table for example a count of rows and you want it at the top. then you'll have to inject it using javascript.

Comment: I see so function is needed in this process, actually I am creating a search box and at the top or above the search result I should put the label or status of the result like:

> There are 38 Results Related to the keyword: videos

Where 38 and the keyword "videos" are both processed using while loop (using SQL). Everything works fine if I display search result info below the loop. Thank you for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

First you are getting error `Undefined variable: passer`. because you are using variable without defining. So define variable before using:

```
$passer = 0; //defining variable 
echo $passer;// you are getting error here

for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    $msg = $i;
}

$passer = $msg;
```

Above code will not give you output as you expecting. because you are `echoing` $passer before initializing it. Try something like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    $msg = $i;
}

$passer = $msg;//initializing first
echo $passer;//output 5
```

Still in above solution i am `echoing` `$passer` after processing of `for` loop.

> Because parser follows top to bottom approach so its impossible output
>   above loop.

Comment: You're not giving answer to his question which is: Is there a way to pass the value of $msg so it will be displayed above the loop?

Comment: @Daan first i found out where is error and pointed out. Then i provided answer with output ans OP expected. Am i still incorrect???

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, now I know that it is impossible using the normal way of PHP. It requires function as what Epodax and Dave said so I can pass the value anywhere. :)

I need to study functions, I am new to PHP by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg = array();
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
  $msg[] = $i;
}

$passer = $msg;
print_r($passer);
```

Comment: the variables are defined inside the loop only. so printing a value before defining is not possible.

Comment: Your code is correct. But sill it doesn't answer question. OP hasn't mentioned he wants to print `array` and i am not downvoter.

Comment: Actually I am creating a search box where the search status or info is placed above the search result let say:

"There are 30 results related to: videos"

then the search result displayed below. The variables that holds the value 38 and the keyword "videos" are inside the while loop. Echoing them below the loops works fine. Echoing them at the top of the search result is not working below as they said PHP is read from top to bottom. :)

Answer (score 0):

**No One Language can output value before define that.**

but you can like this to get your result.

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
  ##passer##
  <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
        $msg = $i;
    } ?>
<?php echo str_replace("##passer##", $msg, ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

Comment: An interesting exception (not exactly): in JavaScript you can use variable before declaring it, and there will be no error (if you declare it later in this scope), because variable declarations are hoised in JavaScript. But you will not get its value of course - its value will be 'undefined'. Example: `console.log(a); var a = 1;` will output undefined, while `console.log(a)` without declaration will result in error.